# Liquibase with Spring Boot and SQL Server throwing error NoClassDefFOundError for class SnowflakeDatabase

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-sql

My Spring Boot application is using local SQL server database is failing on startup with error below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/database/core/SnowflakeDatabase
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.musala.notification.NotificationApplication.main(NotificationApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/database/core/SnowflakeDatabase
    at com.datical.liquibase.ext.storedlogic.storedproc.SnowflakeStoredProcedureSnapshotGenerator.getPriority(Unknown Source) ~[liquibase-commercial-4.17.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getGenerators(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:84) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getContainerTypes(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:306) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getContainerTypes(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:290) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.has(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:101) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:279) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(StandardLockService.java:229) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:113) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:286) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:247) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:214) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2405) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:211) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:197) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:269) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:46) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: liquibase.database.core.SnowflakeDatabase
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

application.properties

```
#
#Liquibase properties
#
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db.changelog-base.yaml
spring.liquibase.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=NG1;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
spring.liquibase.user=sa
spring.liquibase.password=P@ssw0rd
spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema=NOTIFICATION
```

pom.xml dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
   <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My changelog files are `<>-mssql.sql`.

`db.changelog-base.yaml` is in resource folder

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/
```

I was wandering why I it is searching for snowflake database? Because I am using SQL Server.
It will be great if I can get a solution for this issue.

A solution or root cause to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this issue by setting the liquibase-core version to 4.15.0.